# jQuery UI Draggable Clone in Scrollable DIV

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-draggable

I've been working on a project that requires me to use jQuery UI drag and drop functionality. When introducing a scrollable div into the mix, my code is not working as intended, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Goals:

- (Complete) Allow users to drag multiple instances of a smiley or sad face from the ToolBar onto one of the three canvases in the scrollable div. This was done by cloning the helper and removing the orignal droppableShape class.
- (Complete) When a face from the toolbar has been dropped, set the containment of that face to the canvas it was dropped on.
- (Complete) When a face from the toolbar has been dropped, continue to allow the user to move it freely around the canvas it is contained in.
- (Complete) Add the three canvases to a scrollable div for more usability. *This is where my problem is introduced*

The Problem:

- When I add face tool to my scrollable div, the object scrolls with the div and doesn't not "stick" to the desired canvas that the user dropped it on.

What I have tried and did not help:

```
// Make shapes droppable
$(".droppableShape").draggable({
     helper:'clone',
     scrollable: false,
     appendTo: '#canvases_area'
});
```

Here is a fiddle that shows when a face is dropped onto the div, it is static while the canvases scroll. Please let me know if I can provide any further information and thank you for looking at this!

http://jsfiddle.net/fvec4y83/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `faces element` have `absolute position` style, which means they are dependent on the first `relative` or `absolute` parent. In your case this would be the `html` element. But since you have `scroll` on your `canvases_area`, when this scroll, it doesn't affect the `html` until the `canvases_area` get to the top or bottom.

You have many ways of solving your problem, you could remove the `scroll` on canvas_area:

```
#canvases_area {
    //overflow-y: scroll; 
    height:1120px;
    float: right;
}
```

Or set its `position` to `absolute`. Then you'll have to set `top` coordinate and adjust `z-index` so that the draggable face are over it when dragging. Then it would be easier to append to canvases_area, else the calculation to position the element are a bit hard to make.  You could do it like this:

```
#canvases_area {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    height:1120px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

and

```
var newTop = ui.offset.top-$(this).parent().offset().top+$(this).parent().scrollTop()+(ui.draggable.height()/2)

$(this).parent().append(new_field);
 new_field.css({'top': newTop})
```

jsfiddle for last one: http://jsfiddle.net/hwrbLx8c/3/